# Error: The compressed pixel data is missing item delimiters.?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dicom, medical

I am working with few Dicom files and when i try to use dicomread('filename.dcm') in MATLAB it gives the following error:

```
Error using dicomread>processOffsetTable (line 943)
The compressed pixel data is missing item delimiters.
Error in dicomread>processEncapsulatedPixels (line 858)
[offsetTable, offset] = processOffsetTable(metadata);
Error in dicomread>newDicomread (line 232)
      X = processEncapsulatedPixels(metadata, frames);
Error in dicomread (line 86)
[X, map, alpha, overlays] = newDicomread(msgname, frames, useVRHeuristic);
```

I can view this same file in dicom viewing Softwares like onis, di com viewer, Sante Dicom etc.., but when i use dicomread I cannot see see them and get this error

I have so many images of this same format and cannot start from the beginning again, Is there any way I can use this file and view it.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html) online help.

It is common in DICOM world that not all data sets fully comply with DICOM. Most applications (you mentioned in your question) handle the non-compliant part with assumptions and workarounds based on experience and imagination.

Try setting `TF` to `false` to read these files.

Also note the list of supported transfer syntax:

- Little-endian, implicit VR, uncompressed
- Little-endian, explicit VR, uncompressed
- Big-endian, explicit VR, uncompressed
- JPEG (lossy or lossless)
- JPEG2000 (lossy or lossless)
- Run-length Encoding (RLE)
- GE implicit VR, LE with uncompressed BE pixels (1.2.840.113619.5.2)

Check your input image is compressed with one of the above.

Comment: Here is the warning that Matlab gives along with the posted error above: Please try to help me with this i have no idea on what to do with this @A_J.   Warning: Attribute (0002,0010) appears more than once.  Using the last one.   
>In dicomread>getAttributeData at 377     
>In dicomread>getAttributesNeededForReading at 298  
>In dicomread>newDicomread at 197  
>In dicomread at 80  
>In SkullDemo_Mac_V4>compute_Callback at 313  
>In gui_mainfcn at 96  
>In SkullDemo_Mac_V4 at 42  
  In @(hObject,eventdata)SkullDemo_Mac_V4('compute_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

Comment: The tag `0002,0010` is `Transfer Syntax UID`. Why that appears twice in your dataset. You should check with source of image. Also check the value of both the occurrences is same or different. If it is different, then that is a problem.

Comment: Oh ok, I will try to find it . Thanks